# FB Graph API - Create event on behalf of page -> error 403

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to create an event on the behalf of my page using the Facebook Graph API for iOS.
However, I always fail with the error code 403. I have tried to create an event on behalf of me - and surprisingly that works. The permissions are set appropriately as stated [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events)

My code goes like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"Test",@"name",
                                       @"2012-11-11", @"start_time", nil];

    [FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:@"12345/events"
     parameters:postParams
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                         id result,
                         NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", result);

         } else {
             NSLog(@"Success: %@", result);


                     }


     }];
```

How I said, if I set the ID/events to my user ID instead of my Page's ID, it works. Could I have set up something badly on my page? Do I need admin rights for that page?

I found something about access tokens to "Perform the following operations as a Page" [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens). Do I need that? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Are you using the page access token or a user access token? the latter won't work for this - see the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To authenticate as a Page (and from there, edit the events) see this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

In short, authenticate as user who is an an admin of the Page. Then:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=xxx
```

in order to retrieve the access token for the Page (and indeed for any other Pages the user administers).

Then use *that* access token to administer the events for the Page.

Comment: so basically, you need admin permissions to a Page to add an event right? Thank you, I have found an workaround :).